# Command line to generate a parser in F# with mono

Tags: parsing, command-line, f#, mono

I am trying to do some homework with fsyacc, the Yacc parser generator used for F#.

When I run

```
 mono fsyacc.exe --module Stmt Stmt.fsy
```

on the current folder that has the file Stmt.fsy and fsyacc.exe, I got this error message:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies
```

But I do have FSharp.Core.4.3.4/ on my current folder.

FYI, I am testing on an Mac OS X if that matters.  I installed FsLexYacc via nuget:

```
nuget install FsLexYacc
```

and then I made a symbolic link of fsyacc.exe to the current folder.

What is the right command line to parse on Mac, using fsyacc? I am working on an MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions are not very clear in the documentation.  You need the binaries of the tools, which you can build as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/fsprojects/FsLexYacc.git
```

then build it from the command line

```
/build.sh
```

The tools are in FsLexx and FsYacc respectively.  To run them you do:

```
dotnet fslex.dll inputfile -o outputfile
dotnet fsyacc.dll inputfile -o outputfile
```

but more simply you can run one of the samples e.g. LexAndYaccMiniProject. When you build it (e.g. in Visual Studio) you can see that behind the scenes it runs the tools and generates the parsers.  Have a look at the project file to see how this is done.

Now you can create your own project by copying this sample.

Sidenote: You don't need Mono. FsLexYacc runs in .NET core.